# Big Image size low quality export or small image good quality export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, illustration

I have made a vector design in Adobe Illustrator. I need the very best export quality. I have two art boards which contain the same artwork. The difference is, the first art board is 8000px x 8000px , while the second one is only 1000px x 1000px. When I attempt to export my work in the first art board, I can only reach an export quality of 200ppi. While I export in the second art board, I can reach a quality of 1400ppi. I was wondering which export would be at better quality. Keep in mind I am exporting the file as a PNG.

Thank You.

Comment: Since you're exporting files larger than a normal screen you must be making files for print. PNG is meant for pixelart for screen, not for print. If your artwork is pure vector shapes, you would get the best print by simply exporting a PDF. No need to rasterize and no need to think in pixels. What matters is the physical dimensions of your document.

Comment: Yes, I am printing. So doe that mean I should export it as a PDF?

Comment: For print yes, in most cases. That way you keep the vector graphics as geometrical shapes and leave it to the printing device to do the rasterization, resulting in a crisper result. Furthermore you should work in a *print* document with the artboard size set to the physical finished size you want to print. Working in pixels for print doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Wolff - that looks not only like an answer (and a good one at that) - it looks like an answer which the OP will be happy to accept as soon as you turn it from a comment to an answer!

Comment: @GerardFalla, thanks but I felt like I was altering the question too much. I'm often in doubt whether or not to answer a question because I feel like I'm saying: "You're asking the wrong question, you should instead have asked...". At work I try to give people what they need, instead of what they ask for, but I don't know if it's OK here?

Comment: @Wolff - frame challenges are always welcome, as long as you make it clear *why* you're challenging their framing, and as long as you're not dismissive or rude. Sometimes I'll explicitly say "I'm frame challenging here 'cos *XYZ*" - and then also try to address their direct query or if someone else has, I'll mention "so-and-so has addressed the direct query, but I'm also frame challenging 'cos *xyz*". Joojaa busted me for not answering the implied "why?" - and he was right, BTW. In writing not just for our **OP**s, but for future searchers, *whys* & *frame challenges* are ***always*** good.

Answer (score 2):

While editing in Illustrator, your artboard could be 10x10 px. It wouldn't make a difference, as it's vector graphics and you can scale them how you'd like.

I personally do all my Illustrator work in a ~1000 px artboard, when exporting I choose whatever size is needed.